# Passing multiple parameters in linkAction php

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying pass multiple parameters in a linkAction. I can pass one successfully with the following code:

View:

```
<b><div>{!! Html::linkAction('ProductsController@checkout', 'Checkout Now', $string) !!}</div></b>
```

Controller:

```
public function checkout($order)
{
    ..do stuff
}
```

How ever when I add a second parameters it crashes with the following error:

```
ErrorException in ProductsController.php line 119:
Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::checkout()
```

Code below
View:

```
<b><div>{!! Html::linkAction('ProductsController@checkout', 'Checkout Now', $string, $id) !!}</div></b>
```

Controller:

```
public function checkout($order, $id)
{
    ..do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the parameters inside an array.

`Html::linkAction('ProductsController@checkout', 'Checkout Now', [$string, $id])`